# requested URL was not found on raspberry pi server

Tags: raspberry-pi

I had a working server on my raspberry pi which I could connect to from my laptop by writing the rpi's ip address (192.168.0.17) in the browser. Then I tried to install a flask webserver but deleted it later, and now I can't connect to the server by writing 192.168.0.17 in my browser.

Where can I check what I wrote over or did wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check the IP address is correct. On a terminal on your raspberry pi, run the command:

```
ifconfig
```

If that's still 192.168.0.17, move on to the next step, if not, research how to set up a static IP on the raspberry pi.

Step 2: Since you've removed flask webserver, you will no longer be able to access the site from a web browser. Install apache, with php

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Step 3: Try to access the site from the web browser again - It should now be working. You'll have to copy all your website files to the directory /var/www/html in order to see them.